# Build fails due to errors in CLErrorDomain.h

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkmapview

I've been able to build my iOS app in XCode without problems, until suddenly this started happening. On build, I get 2 errors in CLErrorDomain.h-

```
Redefinition of 'NSString' as different kind of symbol
Expected ';' after top level declarator
```

CLErrorDomain.h is part of the framework, and I can't edit or change it. Here's the line of code the is redefining NSString-

```
extern NSString *const kCLErrorDomain;
```

I've restarted XCode, cleaned my project, and it still gives me the same error on build, whether I'm building for the simulator or a device.

What info should I be looking for to figure out how to fix this?

**Update**

I reset to an old commit, and have been rebuilding what I had made. It was fine until I added this code. What in here is making CLErrorDomain give an error?

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,200)];
mapView.delegate = self;
[mapView showsUserLocation];
HotspotAnnotation *annotation = [[HotspotAnnotation alloc] initWitHotspot:_hotspot];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation = _hotspot.coordinates.coordinate;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 20000, 20000);
[mapView setRegion:viewRegion];
```

Comment: Please post the code for the class that is involved with the error, without it it's hard to say why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- I forgot a semicolon after defining an enum.

If this comes up for someone else, look earlier in the code to make sure it's valid.